# Node.js + Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, localhost, atom-editor

I am new with Node.js and Want to connect my sample database with node js and fetch result. I have done below steps.

1. Install MySQL on my Mac
2. Install MySQL Workbench
3. Create database, table and some row in the table.
4. Create Node.js app by following [this](https://medium.com/@avanthikameenakshi/building-restful-api-with-nodejs-and-mysql-in-10-min-ff740043d4be).
5. Install Atom.
6. Install MySQL in the app by `npm install mysql --save`

The application is running fine without SQL query and I'm able to see messages on localhost but when adding SQL connection, it creates an issue and shows the error

> Cannot read property 'query' of undefined.

Contents of `app.js`:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mysql = require("mysql");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql= require('mysql');
var http = require('http');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/api/v1/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/api/v1/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

//Database connection
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('In');
    res.locals.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : '127.0.0.1',
        user     : 'root',
      password : 'q1w2e3r4t5',
        database : 'users'
    });
    res.locals.connection.connect();
  console.log('out');
    next();
});


// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(4001);
```

Contents of `users.js`:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * from userInfo', function (error, results, fields) {
        if(error){
            res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null}));
            //If there is error, we send the error in the error section with 500 status
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
            //If there is no error, all is good and response is 200OK.
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `app.use` methods before the routes are declared.

Refer: [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

From the docs:

> Middleware functions are executed sequentially, therefore the order of
>   middleware inclusion is important.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the code  that connects to the database before when you specify the route of the user.js :

```
    // view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Database connection
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('In');
    res.locals.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : '127.0.0.1',
        user     : 'root',
      password : 'q1w2e3r4t5',
        database : 'users'
    });
    res.locals.connection.connect();
  console.log('out');
    next();
});


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});



// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(4001);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying to use this is as a middleware. This means that every time there's an api call, a new connection to the database will be made. This will make a lot of connections to the database when there are a lot of parallel requests. Ideally, you should create just one connection and use it throughout the app.

create a new file `dbconnection.js`

```
//create connection    
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : '127.0.0.1',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'q1w2e3r4t5',
        database : 'users'
});
//export connection, you can optionally use 
//connection.connect here. The same state of this module is passed everywhere. 
exports.connection = connection;
```

now in your `app.js`, import this using `var connection = require('./dbconnection');` this will automatically create a connection.

You can now use your middleware to set connection in res.locals, but remember to use that before your routes file.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('In');
  res.locals.connection = connection
  console.log('out');
  next();
});

...

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', usersRouter);
```

This should get the work done.